# ESRI leaflet missing tiles

Tags: esri-leaflet, esri-oss

Here's the page I'm working on.  Just click on "Forecasts" tab.  On Chrome and FF browsers.  http://www.weather.gov/mfr/dot

Once on the forecasts tab, you'll see a map below the text links.  Much of the map is grey upon loading. I saw that this can happen if CSS is not loaded, but I have the latest CSS loaded on there.  Can anyone help with this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

since the map container is being created dynamically, you need to call [`map.invalidateSize()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-invalidatesize) when the 'Forecast' panel is toggled.

Comment: Thanks!  That pointed me in the right direction, but I'm still getting the partial tile loading.  http://www.weather.gov/mfr/dot

Can you help with the implementation some?  I don't have control over the entire page's code since it's in a CMS environment and controlled elsewhere.  You can see in the code where I added 

    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([44, -123], 13);
L.Util.requestAnimFrame(mymap.invalidateSize,mymap,!1,mymap._container);

Thanks again.

Comment: you're calling the method too soon.  if you open the browser developer tools and call `mymap.invalidateSize()` *after* toggling the forecast panel, you'll see that it causes all the tiles to load.